# how to handle JSON embedded quotes in title with youtube-data-api-v3

Tags: php, json, youtube-data-api

I have been getting JSON decode errors with data returned by YouTube Data API v3, where the returned JSON includes quotes embedded within the `title` field.

```
$json = curl_init();
$optArray = array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $apiCall,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => FALSE,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => FALSE
);
curl_setopt_array($json, $optArray);
$result = curl_exec($json);
curl_close($json);
```

Error Message: Syntax error

A recent example includes `"videoId": "Q6AYg0oLfC8"`, where this is returned for the title field: `"title": "Trump and His Allies Want You to "Adapt" to the Coronavirus Crisis: A Closer Look"`.

With the PHP 7 JSON decoder v 1.4.0, this JSON does not parse due to the embedded quotes in the `title` field.

What is the best practice to handle embedded quotes in `title` or any other field returned by API JSON responses?

I can upload the JSON returned by YouTube as a file if that helps. (Or can explain how files are attached to Stack Overflow.)

Comment: Cant reproduce the error using the built in `json_decode` in our PHP 7.2 server. You will need to provide actual code that is causing the error, and provide the actual error with `json_last_error` and/or `json_last_error_msg` or whatever else the error is coming from.

Comment: @chibi: See my updated answer below.

Comment: @chibi: Could you check and produce the error message (if any) obtained upon the call of `curl_exec` using `curl_error` like in this official [sample code](https://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php#example-5443)?

Comment: @chibi: Could you also run the `curl` command I've shown in my updated answer below, and compare (e.g. with `diff`) the two JSON files you obtained (the one you already had and the one newly obtained)?

Comment: @chibi: Also post your `$apiCall` (editing out your app key).

Comment: @chibi: Have you tried `curl_error`?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, I never came across *invalid* JSON produced by any of the endpoints of YouTube's Data API.

On the other hand, please note that [embedding quotes in strings](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259#section-7) is perfectly legal JSON. That is, if obeying the prescribed syntax: each quotation mark character to be embedded into a JSON string must be escaped, i.e. must be preceded by a single reverse solidus character -- that is `\`.

Otherwise, this basic feature of JSON is handled seamlessly by [`json_decode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php). (Am assuming that you actually are using `json_decode`.) For example, in case of this simple JSON text:

```
{"foo":"bar\"baz\"boo"}
```

`json_decode` works OK according to [this site](https://www.functions-online.com/json_decode.html). Note that in PHP, that JSON text and the call to that function would look like:

```
$val = json_decode('{"foo":"bar\\"baz\\"boo"}')
```

For to try helping you further, do post here the relevant piece of PHP code that produces the error mentioned, along with the error message(s) generated.

---

**Update upon OP's posting source code**

Upon running the following `curl` command line at a stock GNU/Linux `bash` prompt:

```
$ curl -o Q6AYg0oLfC8.json "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?key=$YOUTUBE_DATA_APP_KEY&id=Q6AYg0oLfC8&part=contentDetails,id,liveStreamingDetails,player,recordingDetails,snippet,statistics,status,topicDetails"
```

I did obtained a valid JSON text. The `title` field looks like shown below:

```
$ grep Q6AYg0oLfC8.json -ne '"title"' -B4
 8-      "id": "Q6AYg0oLfC8",
 9-      "snippet": {
10-        "publishedAt": "2020-07-16T01:00:02Z",
11-        "channelId": "UCVTyTA7-g9nopHeHbeuvpRA",
12:        "title": "Trump and His Allies Want You to \"Adapt\" to the Coronavirus Crisis: A Closer Look",
--
91-        ],
92-        "categoryId": "23",
93-        "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
94-        "localized": {
95:          "title": "Trump and His Allies Want You to \"Adapt\" to the Coronavirus Crisis: A Closer Look",
```

These strings are indeed valid.

Comment: $result = curl_exec($json);
$array = json_decode($result, true);

Comment: @chibi: Do post the entire `curl` sequence of calls, from `curl_init` to `curl_close` (editing out your app key, of course). Just edit your original post, making the source code more visible.

Comment: @chibi: Also do take into account the advice that [IncredibleHat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2960971/incrediblehat) gave you above and post the respective error message too.